# Why didn't Naomi Wildman fall asleep in Bliss

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

I just rewatched [Bliss](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Bliss_(episode)) (Star Trek Voyager 5x14). In this episode the [alien of the week](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Telepathic_pitcher_plant) causes the whole crew to fall asleep with a [neurogenic field](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Neurogenic_field) except for Naomi Wildman, the doctor, and Seven of nine whom Naomi manages to wake up. The reason the doctor wasn’t affected is obvious, and I’m assuming Seven wasn’t affected because of something Borg-related. However, I can’t figure out why Naomi Wildman didn’t fall asleep. Did I miss some hint in the episode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's stated in the episode that the "pitcher plant" attracts its victims by presenting an illusion of everything they ever wanted - in *Voyager*'s case, a wormhole leading back to Earth, and the possibility that all their lives are going to turn out okay (Note especially how Chakotay, a literal terrorist according to the Federation, is offered a prestigious teaching position).

According to the episode, that's why Seven of Nine and Naomi aren't affected: they don't actually *want* to go back to Earth; Seven is afraid of how she'll be received, and Naomi thinks of *Voyager* as her home.

As a hand-wavy scientific explanation, it's possible that the neurogenic field reacts with brain chemicals like serotonin to put victims to sleep, and making the crew happy was just an easy way to accomplish that.

I'm personally not really satisfied with that explanation. Another possibility is, as you say, that Seven was protected by her Borg implants. Namoi may have been protected because she's half Ktarian; it wouldn't be the first time we've seen a mixed-species heritage provide immunity against the Threat of the Week.

Comment: Why aren't you satisfied with the explanation from the episode itself? Wouldn't it be much easier to accept that, than to trust in an ad hoc explanation involving species' immunity?

Comment: @T-1000'sSon I don't remember; I wrote this a year and a half ago. This is why detailed answers are good things

Answer (score 9):

It's explicitly stated by the EMH that the reason why Naomi and Seven weren't affected is because the creature was simply blasting out a very generalised fantasy to each of the crew using its [neurogenic field](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Neurogenic_field) (e.g. feelings of 'home') and allowing their own minds to fill in the blanks. The field itself doesn't *cause* sleep, it's the acceptance of the fantasy world that leads to the comatose state:

Seven and Naomi both consider the Voyager to ***be*** their home and are therefore immune but note that Seven's immunity dissipates after it changes the illusion to something more *specific* to her desires.

> **SEVEN:** *We've cleared the organism.*
>
> **QATAI** [on monitor]: *You've been deceived. We're both still inside it.*
>
> **EMH:** *He's right. I'm reading bioplasmic energy.*
>
> **SEVEN:** *I am impervious to the creature's influence.*
>
> **EMH:** *You were impervious, when it was creating the illusion of Voyager getting home, because you didn't share that desire. But now
>   we're trying to escape, which is what you want.*

---

This isn't the first time the crew have encountered a neurogenic field. In "Waking Moments" a similar field is used to project a **shared** dream to the crew:

> **EMH:** *A neurogenic field created by heightened electrical activity in the brain. It's been occurring in all the sleeping crew members.
>   And that's not all. This is Ensign Kim's brain wave pattern,
>   indicating that he's dreaming in a hyper REM state. This is Crewman
>   Foster's pattern.*
>
> **CHAKOTAY:** *They're identical.*
>
> **EMH:** *Lieutenant Torres, Captain Janeway, Commander Tuvok. I don't know what it means.*
>
> **CHAKOTAY:** *I think I do. Not only are they dreaming, they're all having the same dream. It wasn't just my dream, it was a communal
>   dream.*

Comment: That explains why the illusion of earth didn't seduce them, but how does that explain the sleeping? When Seven is fooled by the later illusion (as you point out), she doesn't fall asleep.

Comment: @Bachrach44 - Based on Janeway's log, it seems to take a couple of days for the sleepiness to take hold whereas the hallucinations start almost instantly.

Answer (score -3):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bliss_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)

"As Voyager returns to consciousness and sets course to the Alpha Quadrant, Qatai is seen returning to the creature. It remains unclear whether Qatai is intent on destroying it or simply returning to a life of delusional captivit"

Found It i Guess ,, But makes me Wounder :-) God do i love Sifi

Comment: It's not clear that this actually answers the question.